# Is there a way to populate this polygon drawer with pre-loaded data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I am currently tinkering on a implementation example of the polygon drawer from the react-map-gl docs. Specifically [this one](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/examples/draw-polygon) [(source code)](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/tree/7.1-release/examples/draw-polygon).

In the example, i don't really understand how (and if) it would be possible to pre-load MapBoxDraw with data. AKA if I can throw a bunch of GeoJSON data into it and open some polygons, ready to edit.

I am currently trying to do it like this (**the relevant lines are prefaced with the HERE keyword**):

#### PolygonControl.tsx

```
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'

import { useGeoMap } from '../../provider/GeoMapProvider'
import DrawControl from './components/DrawControl'
import { ChangeEvent } from './utils/Polygon.props'

export const PolygonControl = () => {
  const { mode, features, setFeatures } = useGeoMap()

  const onUpdate = useCallback((e: ChangeEvent) => {
    console.log('onUpdate', e.features)
    setFeatures((currFeatures) => {
      const newFeatures = { ...currFeatures }
      for (const f of e.features) {
        newFeatures[f.id] = f
      }
      return newFeatures
    })
  }, [])

  const onDelete = useCallback((e: ChangeEvent) => {
    setFeatures((currFeatures) => {
      const newFeatures = { ...currFeatures }
      for (const f of e.features) {
        delete newFeatures[f.id]
      }
      return newFeatures
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {mode.type === 'polygon' && (
        <DrawControl
          position="top-right"
          displayControlsDefault={false}
          defaultMode="draw_polygon"
          controls={{
            polygon: true,
            trash: true,
          }}
          // HERE is where we pass in the pre-loaded polygons
          initialPolygons={features}
          onCreate={onUpdate}
          onUpdate={onUpdate}
          onDelete={onDelete}
        />
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

#### DrawControl.tsx

```
import MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw'
import { useControl } from 'react-map-gl'

import { DrawPolygonControlProps } from '../utils/Polygon.props'

export default function DrawControl(props: DrawPolygonControlProps) {
  useControl<MapboxDraw>(
    () => {
      const draw = new MapboxDraw(props)

      // HERE: Check if there are pre-existing polygons to add
      if (props.initialPolygons) {
        Object.values(props.initialPolygons).forEach((feature) => {
          draw.add(feature)
        })
      }

      return draw
    },
    ({ map }) => {
      map.on('draw.create', props.onCreate)
      map.on('draw.update', props.onUpdate)
      map.on('draw.delete', props.onDelete)
    },
    ({ map }) => {
      map.off('draw.create', props.onCreate)
      map.off('draw.update', props.onUpdate)
      map.off('draw.delete', props.onDelete)
    },
    {
      position: props.position,
    },
  )

  return null
}
```

However, this is giving me the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')` upon calling the draw.add function.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is, I would be very happy if a kind soul could shine some light on a possible solution here. Any extra info which I might have missed and is required will be provided immediately upon request.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** ... Easier - remember to add the ref, see previous answer

Add a new method

```
...
type DrawControlProps = ConstructorParameters<typeof MapboxDraw>[0] & {
  position?: ControlPosition;
  onLoad?: (evt: { map: MapRef }) => void; // <- Here
  onCreate?: (evt: {features: object[]}) => void;
  onUpdate?: (evt: {features: object[]; action: string}) => void;
  onDelete?: (evt: {features: object[]}) => void;
};

export default function DrawControl(props: DrawControlProps) {
  const mapDraw = useRef<MapboxDraw | null>(null) // Ref need

  useControl<MapboxDraw>(
    () => {
      const draw = new MapboxDraw(props)
      mapDraw.current = draw
      return draw
    },
    ({map}: {map: MapRef}) => {
      if (props.onLoad) map.on('load', () => props.onLoad(mapDraw.current)); // <- Here
      map.on('draw.create', props.onCreate);
      map.on('draw.update', props.onUpdate);
      map.on('draw.delete', props.onDelete);
    },
    ({map}: {map: MapRef}) => {
      if (props.onLoad) map.off('load', () => props.onLoad); // <- Here
      map.off('draw.create', props.onCreate);
      map.off('draw.update', props.onUpdate);
      map.off('draw.delete', props.onDelete);
    },
    ...
  );

  return null;
}

DrawControl.defaultProps = {
  onLoad: () => {},
  onCreate: () => {},
  onUpdate: () => {},
  onDelete: () => {}
};
```

Then use like this:

```
const onLoadDraw = (drawInstance) => {
    if (existingFeature) {
        drawInstance.add(existingFeature)
        const polygonId = existingFeature.id
        drawInstance.changeMode('simple_select', { featureId: polygonId })
    }
}
...
<DrawControl
    ...
    onLoad={onLoadDraw}
    onUpdate={onUpdate}
    onCreate={onCreate}
    onDelete={onDelete}
/>
```

Old answer, just in case

we need to adapt the DrawControl.tsx file a little.

The main idea is to keep a reference to the MapboxDraw instance to be able to manipulate it, in particular via the ['add'](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/main/docs/API.md#addgeojson-object--arraystring) method.

```
...

export default function DrawControl(props: DrawControlProps) {
  const mapDraw = useRef(null); // <- initialize a ref

  useControl<MapboxDraw>(
    () => {
      const draw = new MapboxDraw(props); // <- Store instance in a variable
      mapDraw.current = draw; // <- Assign it to ref
      return draw; // <- return instance
    },
    ({map}: {map: MapRef}) => {
      map.on('draw.create', props.onCreate);
      map.on('draw.update', props.onUpdate);
      map.on('draw.delete', props.onDelete);
    },
    ({map}: {map: MapRef}) => {
      map.off('draw.create', props.onCreate);
      map.off('draw.update', props.onUpdate);
      map.off('draw.delete', props.onDelete);
    },
    {
      position: props.position
    }
  );

  // We can now use the MapboxDraw instance (via ref) and use "add". 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapDraw.current && props.initialFeatures) {
      props.initialFeatures.forEach(feature => {
        mapDraw.current.add(feature);
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return null;
}
...
```

Here's how it's used on the Map side:

```
<DrawControl
  position="top-left"
  displayControlsDefault={false}
  controls={{
    polygon: true,
    trash: true,
  }}
  defaultMode="simple_select"
  onCreate={onUpdate}
  onUpdate={onUpdate}
  onDelete={onDelete}
  initialFeatures={[
    {
      id: 'af82dd7ccff1acdb02d5576098bcca01',
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        coordinates: [
          [
            [-4.1459062318538145, 48.69254630799924],
            [-4.145435776488171, 48.69134292282183],
            [-4.1428482719773, 48.69131704325446],
            [-4.142867874283979, 48.69258512639723],
            [-4.1459062318538145, 48.69254630799924],
          ],
        ],
        type: 'Polygon',
      },
    },
  ]}
/>
```